# Ошибка при установке пакета error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, gcc, centos, django

Доброго времени суток. Ребята, помогите с проблемой: ошибка при установке пакета:

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

По всему гуглу описывается исправление в таком виде:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Но это сработает на ubuntu либо debian, а как быть, если у меня centos? На нем это не срабатывает!

Comment: @siren, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: ошибка в gcc может возникнуть по разным обстоятельствам, как минимум нужно добавьте в текст первую строчку из gcc лога, которая содержит слово error.

Answer (score 3):

Вместо apt-get в CentOS/RHEL yum.

[CentOS / RHEL 7: Install GCC (C and C++ Compiler) and Development Tools](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-rhel-7-redhat-linux-install-gcc-compiler-development-tools/).

А вообще-то см. в гугле

```
 install python development centos
```